# How can be estimated maximum system usage?

Tags: performance, requirements

We have web service connected to REST API a we need to estimate maximum usage for specifying HW requirements.

- Inputs - We know estimated number of users and we know number of requests that we're able to process on one server instance per some time unit.
- Required output - number of server instances needed to process all requests, including unexpected peaks.
- Problem we are facing - there can be usage peaks during hours and not all customers will make the same number of requests per some time unit etc.

How can be modeled such problem? Is there some technique or we can only estimate the final usage?

Answer (score 0):

For performance queries like this - there is only so much you can answer on paper, and to have full confidence you will eventually need to setup a test environment, and test under expected load.

At the simplest, you obviously need to model / test your peak volumes.
To perform some paper based sizing, you need to look for benchmarks for the technologies your are using, as different tech stacks will require very different underlying hardware to support.